# Google Cloud Build: How to increase RAM memory?

Tags: google-cloud-build

How do I increase RAM memory on Google Cloud Build?

I'm getting this error:

`Step #1: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I'm using the REST API.

I'm trying to find the RAM memory config, but I only found a property called `diskSizeInGb`. 
The default for `diskSizeInGb`is 100GB, and it's just a React app I'm compiling, so I don't think that's the case.

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#buildoptions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The RAM of the instance is dependant on the [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.MachineType) you are using, if you need more RAM in your build, you will need to use a different value for `machineType`.

By default, Cloud Build uses a "n1-standard-1" instance to run the build which has 3.75 GB of memory, however, you can change it to a "n1-highcpu-8" which has double that. You can find the information regarding the instance types over [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_machine_type).

Keep in mind that Cloud  Build only accepts "n1-standard-1", "n1-highcpu-8" and "n1-highcpu-32" machines as mentioned in the documentation, and that each has a [different billing](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/pricing).

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

This is very unclear... you would think that a `n1-highcpu-8` would provide 8gb of memory, but if you put a command like `RUN free -h` throughout the Dockerfile, it will never consume more than about 2gb.  This is because of kubernetes, I think, not the machine type.

```
INFO[0928] Running: [/bin/sh -c free -h]                
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        719M        178M        608K        6.9G        6.8G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

This output makes no sense: 8gb total, used 719mb, but only 179mb free

Comment: the "8" in `n1-highcpu-8` refers to the number of CPUs, not the memory

Comment: it's a coincidence in this case.  It's both 8 CPUs and 8G memory.  What is non-obvious is that in certain configurations the `/tmp` disk is a ramdisk, which means that even under a very low CPU/mem load, you can run out of memory by using the tmpfs.